Bash terminal lagging one input behind
After a recent update, I've noticed that working on any terminal for more than a few minutes causes a delay between inputting a keypress and seeing it reflected on the screen.
Specifically, if I were to type "Hello, World" I would see only "Hello, Worl" - but as soon as I press another key, the "d" appears and that new key becomes hidden instead. When I press yet another key, the previous one becomes visible, and so on.
Waiting somewhere between one and twenty seconds sometimes causes the keypress to appear, but that's not exactly conducive to work at any reasonable pace, especially since it also affects arrow keys and navigation.
I haven't noticed this behavior anywhere outside of a bash shell and anything running inside it (mostly vim). The computer's been restarted a few times, the CPU is not under load, and everything's up to date (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, GNU bash 5.1.16(1)-release).
A similar question was asked about 2 years ago, but there was no conclusive answer.
How do I go about troubleshooting this behavior?

Are you connected via ssh, or sitting directly at the machine?

If connected local, Wayland or X11? (I had this issue when testing Wayland; went back to X11). Does it also happen on the console (ctrl-alt-f1)? Did you try alternative terminals (xterm for example)?

@choroba I am sitting directly at the machine - thankfully (hopefully?) it's not an issue with the internet connection.

@LjmDullaart I am on X11 right now - Wayland gave me issues as well and I switched back a while ago. Alternative terminals do NOT exhibit the laggy behavior; I'll work using xterm while I continue troubleshooting this. Console appears to be currently inaccessible due to a separate issue with nvidia drivers tainting the kernel (?).

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509058/input-delay-on-terminal-ubuntu-22-04-4.

@egmont This was indeed the problem, and it's been fixed! Thank you for the link.
